# Matplotlib graph placement

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need a little help with formatting. How do I change the distance between the second and third graph

```
   from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


   fig  = plt.figure(1)
   graph1 = fig.add_subplot(3,1,1)
   graph2 = fig.add_subplot(3,1,2)
   norm =  fig.add_subplot(3,1,3)

   graph1.set_title(TITLE + '\nscaling factor: ' +str(round(rescale,3)))
   norm.set_title('Circle and Oval Height Difference')
   norm.set_xlabel(XLABEL +'(Degrees)')
   norm.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.13,1), prop={'size':8})
   plt.ylabel('Heights (nm)')


   graph1.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.13,1),prop={'size':8})
   graph2.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.13,1),prop={'size':8})
   fontP = FontProperties()
   fontP.set_size('small')
```

[image]

Comment: Are the x-axes meant to be identical? (If so, you can save a lot of space by explictly sharing them and only displaying the bottom x-axis.)

Comment: Yeah, they are identical,so how can I change it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=desiredspace)
```

I'm pretty sure, the way matplotlib is, there could be some more ways to do that, but it solves my problem, even having to figure out by hand the best value.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

The quick answer is [`fig.subplots_adjust`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.subplots_adjust), setting hspace to a larger value.  Unfortunately this also inserts some space between the top two graphs, but this may be good anyways, depending on what you want.  As Joe says, I often remove the x-axes if they are the same.

If you want to have uneven spacing, i.e. more spacing between 2 and 3 than between 1 and 2, you need to explicitly instantiate the Axes at a particular position using [`fig.add_axes`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes).